# How to delete a picture in powerpoint from VBA code in excel before pasting new object?

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

Very new to VBA.
This is code i'm using to paste into blank powerpoint slide (which has been working fine) but when i need to update for the next months data not sure how to delete old picture before new picture is pasted...
any help appreciated.

```
  Sheets("Presentation").Select
  Range("b53:w99").Select
  Selection.CopyPicture Format:=xlPicture
  With PptActvWin
    .View.GotoSlide Index:=3
    .View.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPastePicture
    pptApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Left = 2.5 * 72 * 0.393700787
    pptApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Top = 2.5 * 72 * 0.393700787
    pptApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.ScaleHeight 0.45, msoTrue, 
  msoScaleFromTopLeft
    pptApp.ActiveWindow.ViewType = ppViewNormal
  End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

before pasting your picture, loop through all shapes in the active slide and delete 'em.

```
With PptActvWin
.View.GotoSlide Index:=3
For Each oSh In .View.Slide.Shapes
    If oSh.Type = msoPicture Then
        oSh.Delete
    End If
Next
.View.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPastePicture
pptApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Left = 2.5 * 72 * 0.393700787
pptApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Top = 2.5 * 72 * 0.393700787
pptApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.ScaleHeight 0.45, msoTrue, msoScaleFromTopLeft
pptApp.ActiveWindow.ViewType = ppViewNormal
```

End With